# anyone know why I keep getting duplicate images

Tags: php, mysql

Its suppose to be a gallery that displays images from two joined tables. Somehow two duplicate images instead of one keeps popping up. It only happens when I joined the tables. Is there a way to prevent this using javascript or some php code. I'm I doing something wrong.

Comment: Run the query separately in the mysql monitor to see what you're getting back. and exactly what is the point of the `$row['name']['long ugly chunk of html']['more html']` line anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your query to this.

```
     $sql = "  SELECT images.id, header.username, images.message, images.name
   FROM images
   INNER JOIN header
   ON images.message=header.file 
   group by images.id; ";
```

- you missed to `GROUP BY` image id to dont get dublicates

Comment: really, let me check it out.

Comment: thanks a million. I wasted so much time trying to figure it out. I should of asked.